# Use an attachment in multiple posts

Tags: posts, attachments, api

I have an attachment in a post and I want to attach it to another post without detaching it from the first post, using the WP API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so simple to do this. In my code change post_parent field from the attachment with new post Id.

```
//take all image-attachments from a post to create post for each 
    $images =& get_children( array (
                        'post_parent' => $event_id,
                        'post_type' => 'attachment',
                        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                    ));


            if ( empty($images) ) {
                // no attachments here
            } else { 
                //handle each attachment
                foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

                    $this->addPost( $post_id, $attachment_id, $attachment );
                }
....

...
function addPost($post_id, $attach_id, $attach)
        {
            // Create post object

            $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => 'title',
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'post'
            );

            // Insert the post into the database
            // create new post that want to reattach the attatchment


            $this->unhookFromSavePost(); // see http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#Avoiding_infinite_loops
            $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post ); //get post's id 
            $this->hookToSavePost();
            $attach->post_parent = $new_post_id; // post_id 
            $newAddedAttachment = wp_insert_attachment( $attach );
```

If you want to duplicate the attachment and use it in more posts you have to follow the steps here: [wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment).Also, it is posible to copy $attach in new object but you have to unset the ID property of this object.

```
$new_attach = $attach;
$new_attach->post_parent = $new_post_id;
unset($new_attach[0]);     // unset first property or unset($new_attach[ID]);
wp_insert_attachment( $new_attach);
```

Comment: Why there is an argument `$attach_id`, if you don't use it ?

Answer (score 4):

When inside of the media uploaded in the post edit screen, just search for your previously attached media and embed it in your new post.

The relationship between posts and attachments is preserved in the database. While an attachment can only belong to one post, it can still be embedded in many posts without worry.

Comment: I don't believe this is true. Media is attached to 1 or 0 posts, not multiple. `post_parent` contains one value.

Comment: Yes this is true. I want to do this with wp api.

Comment: That's true, however i assume the user is talking about attaching one piece of media to multiple posts. Which you can do

Comment: Not whats reflected in the db. However I see I missed the wp api requirement, since it's not tagged as such

Comment: Well, an image or piece of media can be _mentioned_ in any number of posts, but it can only be attached to one post. And what you wrote seems to imply otherwise. "The relationship between posts and attachments is preserved in the database. One attachment can be attached to many posts without worry."

Comment: I agree it was ambiguous, my apologies.

Comment: It begs the question, why is it an issue to create multiple attachments for the same media in the db. To answer the initial question I cannot think of a way to do it other than storing the attachment id in a meta field like the way featured images are done.

Comment: I believe @thanassis wishes to re-assign the media to another post, programmatically. I think a plugin exists for this, but it would be tedious if there were many attachments that needed this treatment

Comment: I don't worry about my db now. Later I will may delete duplicates. I try a solution in my question that not work and I am looking for something like this.